# Brightcove Video player not working on Internet explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer

I am using Brightcove Video player to my web application. The requirement of this this player is html5 or flash player. Now in I.E. 8 we all know that it partially support html5. I would like to know is there any plugin available which get installed to the client browser before playing the video. If any support related to it let me know in details please note i do not want that browser need to install the flash player.

Comment: The player is likely to fall back to Flash in IE8. Is Flash installed?

Answer (score 1):

Brightcove delivers Flash to ALL desktop browsers, even those that support HTML5. Brightcove's HTML5 video delivery is reserved for mobile browsers and then only iOS and Android are supported. This was the answer I was given a few months back anyhow.

In any case, IE8 does not support HTML5 video as far as I know, at least not without a shim or some other hack.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add something to this response.

As long as you are using their Smart Player API - you are more or less safe for any backward compatibility and as mentioned by Brian - you will receive Flash on desktop UNLESS you force html5 (which is not recommended at all) or you are only using their video api to retrieve the video.

Other than that - he is correct that HTML5 auto switch on mobile only (and HLS live stream delivery on iOS).